# Not able to access directory inside the docker container

Tags: docker, directory, docker-container

Trying to expose the content of an Application(In docker container) using Rest API.Even though the directory is there inside the container i am not able to access the directory from REST API..Java Jar files are deployed inside the container itself..
I am using this code to zip a directory and then later download it..And is inside the container..

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> downloadFile(String projectPath,String projectName) throws IOException, InterruptedException  {
        Process p = null;
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"zip","-r",projectName+".zip",projectName+"/"});
        pb.directory(new File(projectPath));
        p = pb.start();
```

I am getting this error:
message": "Cannot run program \"zip\" (in directory \"/home/ccm_root/ccm_wa/InformixDB/XYZ-1\"): error=2, No such file or directory"
Even though this directory is present...

Comment: Is there a `/usr/bin/zip` inside the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze Currently zip is not there in `/usr/bin/zip`  inside the container.                                                                                            
 Yes it occurred to me that zip command might not be there in the container.So i had created a new docker file with `RUN sudo yum install -y zip `..But that also didn't work..Do you think that is the issue?

Comment: Yes, that would cause an error “zip: ... no such file or directory”.